# Take background outside the div

Tags: css, html, background

I want to position the background image of a div outside it. Something like `backgroundPosition: -100px 0px`. My problem is that it acts like the `div` has the overflow property = hidden.

I've made a scratch of what I need: http://screencast.com/t/3zo0hp8A3

Comment: is it possible to set the background in the element outside the `DIV`? I mean in the element which contains your `DIV`.

Comment: Background is called background with purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the way you are thinking of.. Is not possible in any browser!

Made you a small example: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/bFBfh/

This is what Curt was referring to: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/bFBfh/3/

The last solution is the correct way to go, based on your specifications. If you would explain more about your higher goal, then maybe we could come up with even better solution.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I've applied. The higher goal is to make an image rotator with a "playlist" in the left side of the view. When an item is selected, I wanted to make the item's background from the playlist to appear above the main image. Here is a screenshot of what I made : http://screencast.com/t/bnjRTWWq

Comment: You know what.. I would make it with two div's just like in the fiddle. I would always have the wrapper container, overlapping on the elephant.. If you do some research, then you might even find a cool jQuery animation script. That would move the guitar smoothly on hover ;) **NOTE:** You probably want to use two different guitar pictures. Opacity variables wont work in this case.

Comment: This product must be fully customizable, so the background images can be changed or moved when an item is selected, at :hover and at click. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible and will be difficult to get working on multiple browsers.

I think the best option would be to put 'Div2' inside another div, with the background set to that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with background, but you can use an html image with `position:relative` or `absolute` with a negative `left`.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to find other solutions to this problem.